# Ошибка, Не может найти главный класс

Tags: java

пишу небольшую программу, столкнулся с такой проблеммой не могу скомпилировать, т к ява не может найти главный класс,погуглил проблему но ничего толком не нашел

```
   package com.evghenii.main;

    import com.evghenii.text.Text;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Rezept {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
         init();
            System.out.println(Text.get("Menu-HELP"));
        }

        private static void init(){
            Text.init();
            GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment =  GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            try {
                graphicsEnvironment.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,new File("fonts/17574.ttf")));
            } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    package com.evghenii.model;

    public abstract class Common {

        public void postAdd(){

        }
        public  void postEdit(){

        }
        public  void postRemove(){

        }

    }




package com.evghenii.text;

import java.util.HashMap;

final public class Text {
    private static HashMap<String,String> date = new HashMap<>();

    public static void init (){
        date.put("MENU-HELP","Помощь");
        date.put("MENU-Auswahl","Выбор");


    }

    public static String get(String key){
       return date.get(key);
    }


    public  static String[] getMonths(){
        String [] monts = new String[12];

        monts [0] = get("January");
        monts [1] = get("Februar");
        monts [2] = get("Marz");
        monts [3] = get("April");
        monts [4] = get("Mai");
        monts [5] = get("Juni");
        monts [6] = get("Juli");
        monts [7] = get("August");
        monts [8] = get("September");
        monts [9] = get("Oktober");
        monts [10] = get("November");
        monts [11] = get("December");




        return monts;

    }


}
```

буду рад помощи,спасибо

Comment: мы должны догадаться, как именно вы это компилируете, чем пользуетесь?

Comment: да,извините intellij idea

Comment: в идее есть билд конфигурации, где можно указать главный класс. Укажите его там руками.

Comment: имеете ввиду File-Proekt Strukture - SdkS - ClassPatch? что именно я там должен прописать?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/DNUqgGc.png

Comment: http://priscree.ru/img/51abac55d774b6.jpg у меня все так же,может в другом проблема?

Comment: Вы пишете, что не сможете скомпилировать, но ваши слова расходятся с [вашим скриншотом](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9BDR.jpg), так что мне не понятно даже что у вас за проблема.

Comment: Может все-таки на начальном этапе научиться собирать и компилировать программы в консоли, а не в IDE? Понять что такое -sourcepath и -classpath и т.д.  Во-первых это интересно, а во-вторых глядишь и IDE настроить правильно легче будет.

Comment: И может стоит попробовать IDE попроще. Intellij для шибко умных, простому человеку в ней не разобраться. Я например делал несколько попыток. За что только деньги требуют. Хорошо что netbeans пока существует. Потом есть eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался достаточно просто, почему-то был не правильно указанно выходной файл, изменив его, все заработала